# scite editor and gcc setting up?

Tags: gcc, ide, editor, notepad++, scite

Hey there, In class we're using the Scite editor with gcc and its a tad outdated. I was wondering how you would "attach"(For lack of a better term) gcc to scite so that it would compile the code when I hit the compile icon?. Also would this process be the same when using other text editors like notepad++.

-cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is copied form cpp.properties (Options -> Edit Properties -> Open cpp.properties)

```
ccopts=-pedantic -Os
cc=g++ $(ccopts) -c $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).o
ccc=gcc $(ccopts) -c $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).o

make.command=make
command.compile.*.c=$(ccc) -std=c99
command.build.*.c=$(make.command)
command.go.*.c=./$(FileName)
# To make the Go command both compile (if needed) and execute, use this setting:
#command.go.needs.*.c=gcc $(ccopts) -std=c99 $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName)

command.compile.$(file.patterns.cplusplus)=$(cc)
command.build.$(file.patterns.cplusplus)=$(make.command)
command.go.$(file.patterns.cplusplus)=./$(FileName)
command.go.needs.$(file.patterns.cplusplus)=g++ $(ccopts) $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName)

command.build.*.h=$(make.command)
```